# Simplyfying a lot of cubes

Tags: modeling

I am building a library in Blender... and I am a real newbie. Just started out 4 days ago.

I fear I have been a bit over zealous and created a cube for every book in the library. And hit about the edge of what blender can take on my computer and I have So much more to add. I hit about 20000 and need another 50000 :)

Most books share a face with the book next too it or at least share part of one.

Is there any easy way to simplify the rows of book in my library or make the books into an object even tough they don't share Materials?

I"d Like to keep them apart if possible but that is just impossible I think.

Comment: Blender is a visual application, images/gifs/a video of what you have vs what you want makes it easier for us to help you otherwise it's just speculation and general tips.

Comment: Did you use an array modifier, or did you manually create all those books??

Comment: Could you try adding all of the cube geometry in a single object? Blender is generally good at handling many _vertices/edge/faces_, but has more trouble with a whole pile of _objects_.

Comment: @Vince Scalia I duplicated each book 1000's of times (then randomly changed matherial an height of some) don't know the first thing about arrays in Blender. (Will look that up)

Comment: Are you doing it with python, or by hand? If you switch to edit mode for the duplication, I suspect things will work nicer.

Comment: OOOK... this just got *a lot* harder. I don't want to tell you to destroy everything you made and make an array... So i'll find another way.

Comment: @ Vince Scalia Honestly I don't mind if it solves my problem. As I said I am a noob and am willing to learn. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: PLease user2859 can you teach me how to do this? this looks exactly what I need. Pretty please With a cherry on top :)

Comment: SE isn't really the place for lengthy tutorials. At the moment there is not enough information to answer your original question. Here is more or less (4k instead of 5k books/rack) how I build the [test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04CbmtCME9Od2dBUms/view?usp=sharing): [Part 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04CV2lmTlg4Mmd5cHM/view?usp=sharing), [Part 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04CYU1SVzFCeVg2UG8/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @user2859 You are a life saver I wish I could give you more points this has helped me a lot and I will be using this technique for years to come. Thank You.